# Displaying a <select> as a <table> while maintaining <option>s

Tags: php, html-table

I currently have a `<select>` element populated by data from a DB (See screenshot below)

The PHP that renders it is simple:

```
print "<select>";
print "<option name=\"$wo_num\" value=\"$wo_num\">$order_date: #$wo_num - $client ($problem)</option>";
print "</select>";
```

The `<select>` element looks like this currently:

http://www.captainscall.site11.com/temp_stuff/select.png

I want to know the best approach to making my `<select>` element displayed more like a table than straight lines of data *while maintaining the ability to 'choose and option'*

I have tried simply embedding a `<table>` inside the `<select>` to no avail.

I don't necessarily need a `<table>`; I'm just going for a better aesthetic for the user.

Comment: Your `<option>` tag should not have a name attribute (just a value or an id) the `<select>` should be `<select name="$wo_num">` See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html

Comment: @AlexP My `<select>` actually does have a `name`, I didn't include it here. Didn't know that about `<option>`, though, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to rethink what you are trying to do here. Clearly there is allot of data in the select element, which would be better separated from the actual select *option* you are trying to give the user- A radio is one option already suggested.

The bottom line is that the input should be short and concise and the data should be displayed via HTML. This not only opens up the door for better styling via CSS but it would be allot easier for your users to read and understand what they are actually selecting.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<table>` and put a radio button in one of the columns instead of using a select element.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
<select size="20" name="namehere" multiple>
```

set the size to the be the same as the number of records. Use CSS to style the multiple select box. Note this approach however will allow multiple selections.

Comment: why the neg vote? This was an alternative solution, no need for the -1

Comment: I gave you a +1 to get back to 0